# Pandas groupby performance improvement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following operation:

```
output = (df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer.dropna(how='all').sum(axis=1)
                 .groupby(level=0).sum()
                 .rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))
```

`df_pointer` is a big container which is initially full of zeros, but it gets more and more dense.

`df1_pointer` is a multiindex dataframe (with two levels) very sparse, full of `nan` and zeros.

I need to both sum across columns and then across the level 1 index (called "Layer").

There are few peculiarities I know.

For each key of the level 0 index ("Entity") I have exactly eight observations in the "Layer" index:

```
Column             1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15
Entity    Layer
1        1        1    NaN    0.0    0.0    NaN    NaN    0.0    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN    0.0    0.0    72.0
        2        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    0.0
        3        NaN    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
        4        NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    0.0    NaN    19.5
        5        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.32435    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
....
```

I tried:

```
output = (df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer.dropna(how='all').sum(axis=1)
                 .groupby('Entity').sum()
                 .rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))

6.8 ms ± 829 µs per loop (mean ± standard deviation of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

output2 = (df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer.dropna(how='all').sum(axis=1)
                 .groupby(level=0).sum()
                 .rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))

7.71 ms ± 518 µs per loop (mean ± standard deviation of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

output2 = (df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer[df1_pointer!=0].dropna(how='all').sum(axis=1)
                 .groupby('Entity').sum()
                 .rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))

7.96 ms ± 429 µs per loop (mean ± standard deviation of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

output3 = (df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer[df1_pointer!=0].dropna(how='all').sum(axis=1)
                 .unstack('Layer').sum(axis=1)
                 .rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))

9.26 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`trigger` is just the column name for a particular iteration.
Sometimes it is a list of numbers sometimes is just a number. In this example it comes from the following list of column names: `trigger_list=list(range(1,16))`

Comment: Is here droping rows with missing values necessary? Not just `(df_pointer
            .add(df1_pointer.sum(axis=1).sum(level=0).rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))` ?

Comment: @jezrael the real dataframe is very big and (if I remember correctly) dropping the NaNs speeds up the whole thing.
I will test and update the question

Comment: hmmm, maybe if use `(df_pointer             .add(df1_pointer.fillna(0).sum(axis=1).sum(level=0).rename(str(trigger)).to_frame(), fill_value=0))` ?

Comment: @jezrael your suggestion gives the following, so not an improvement unfortunately.

7.58 ms ± 655 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 100 loops each)

But thanks, didn't know I could sum over a specific index. Maybe I can make the dataframe into a sparse array and then sum over the index.